# Is a valid correlation function on $R^2$ (a plane) also a valid correlation function on a cylinder

Tags: correlation, spatial

Suppose to have a valid correlation function on $R^2$ that depends on the distance. For example if  the distance between two point is $h$, the correlation function can be $\exp(-\phi h)$, where $\phi$ is a parameter.
Now if instead of  $R^2$ we are on a cylinder: $R \times D$ where $D$ is a circle. My question is:
The correlation function based on the distance is again a valid correlation function on the cylinder?

Or maybe the question can be expressed in a different way: how can I prove that a correlation function on a generic space is a valid correlation function?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. By "circle" do you mean something like a modular integer space, or a continuous analog? Leaving $R^{2}$ aside for a moment. How would you calculate a mean in such a number system? How about a variance?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your question, maybe i need to add some more details to clarify the problem. For example consider a gaussian process $\omega(s, c)$ where $s \in R$ and $c \in D=[0,2 \pi)$ and suppose that $\omega(s, c)$ has zero mean and the correlation between two point $(s,c), (s^{\prime},c^{\prime})$  is $\exp(-\phi \sqrt{(s-s^{\prime})^2+(\pi-|\pi-|c-c^{\prime}||)^2  })$, (to clarify, $\pi-|\pi-|c-c^{\prime}||$ is equivalent to the minimum arc length between two angle in a unit circle). My question is: Is this correlation function  positive definite?

Comment: @Alexis Another way to appreciate the thrust of this question is to adopt a very general viewpoint in which a stochastic process $X$ is defined on a Riemannian manifold $M$. Its correlation function is $C(x,y)=\text{Cor}(X(x),X(y))$ for $x,y\in M$. An arbitrary function $C:M^2\to\mathbb{R}$ *can* be such a correlation function provided it defines a nonnegative-definite form for all finite subsets $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}\subset M$. When $C(x,y)=\gamma(\text{dist}(x,y))$ for some $\gamma$, $C$ is *isotropic.* For the usual (flat) cylinder, what functions $\gamma$ arise from isotropic processes?

Comment: I am wonder if we can see the problem as following: a correlation function is a valid correlation function if is positive definite. This mean that the following must hold: $\sum_i \sum_j c_i c_j \gamma(dist(x_i,x_j))=\sum_i \sum_j c_i c_j \gamma(h_{i,j})\ge 0$ for all $c_i, c_j \in R$ . Since the function $\gamma$ depends only on the distance, where is the difference if we are on $R^2$ or $R \times D$? in both cases the distance belongs to the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question:

If we move from a covariance function of a linear domain, $R^d$ to a cylinder, we have to prove (i.e. check if it is positive definite) if it is a valid covariance function unless we think to the cylinder as a object in $R^3$ and then we use the distance in $R^3$.

Unfortunately i am not sure i could post some examples on the cylinder because we are still working on it, and the results will be published.

But we can ask a different, but similar, question: Is a covariance function on $\mathbb{R}$ be valid also in $\mathbb{S}$. There are two paper that answer to this question: "When is a truncated covariance function on the line a covariance function on the circle? Andrew T.A. Wood" and "Simple tests for the validity of correlation function models on the circle" of Gneiting.

As an example (taken to the Gneiting paper) the covariance function: $\frac{1}{2}\left(\exp( -t^2)+(1+3|t|)(  1-|t|)_+^3   \right)$

where $t$ is the distance and $(  1-|t|)_+^3 = (  1-|t|)^3$ if $(  1-|t|)^3>0$ and 0 otherwise, is not positive definite in a circle.

Comment: There's a logical flaw in this argument: many correlation functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ will still remain positive-definite even on the cylinder $\mathbb{R}^1\times S^1$.  Some (but not all) of them may become *semidefinite.*  It would be interesting if you could post an example of one that actually becomes indefinite.

Comment: Ok, yes, you are right, my mistake, some covariance functions are still valid. I edit my previous post